# php mysql jquery Select One Item from a form list and set the value of "1" to a field the rest set to "0"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox, radio-button

i have been struggling.

I have a FORM that has a list of items.
I only want to allow the selection of one item from this list and mark the item in my database as featured. I have tried radio buttons as well but the input name is different for each.

Form:

```
  <td class="right"><input name="top_cat[<?php echo $cat['cat_id']; ?>][featured]" type="checkbox" class="featured" value="<?php echo $cat['featured'] ?>"  />
        </td>
```

Jquery on form:

```
    $(function() {

$(".featured").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1){
        $(this).attr('checked',"checked");
        }

});
$(".featured").click(function(){

    $(".featured").removeAttr('checked');
    $(".featured").val('0');


    $(this).val('1');
    $(this).attr('checked',"checked");
    });
```

In my mysql update:

```
                foreach ($data['top_cat'] as $cat_id => $value) {

$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cat SET featured='" . $this->db->escape($value['featured']) . "' WHERE cat_id = '" . (int)$cat_id . "'");

}
```

This works to a degree, it adds the value of "1" to the database for the item but leaves the previously checked item as "1", it needs to be "0".

I am sure i am over complicating this, any help or nudges in the right direction would appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST will contain only the checked checkboxes, so your foreach loop is probably just looping once.

Use a radio button with the one name like `top_cat`, the value will hold the `$cat['cat_id']`. Now once you submit read the selected radio button with something like `$_POST['top_cat']` or `$data['top_cat']`

Use radio button like:

```
<input name="top_cat" type="radio" class="featured" value="<?php echo $cat['cat_id'] ?>"  />
```

and remove the loop and use php like:

```
$selected = (int)$data['top_cat'];
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cat SET featured='1' WHERE cat_id = $selected ");

// set all others to non-featured
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cat SET featured='0' WHERE cat_id != $selected ");
```

I am not sure how your database is setup but i think this should do the trick

Comment: Your a star...i have been trying to achieve this for a day now(embarrassed to say). Worked like a dream with a little editing for my setup.

Answer (score 0):

i think because it is updating only currently selected  item ,

so you need to run the update query which update to 0 all the previous item.

Try this:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cat SET featured='1' WHERE cat_id = '" . (int)$cat_id . "'");

foreach ($data['top_cat'] as $cat_id => $value) { 
  $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cat SET featured='0' WHERE cat_id = '" . (int)$cat_id . "'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response:I tried   foreach ($data['top_cat'] as $cat_id => $value) {
  if ($this->db->escape($value['featured'])==1) {
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cat SET featured='1' WHERE cat_id = '" . (int)$cat_id . "'");}else{
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cat SET featured='0' WHERE cat_id = '" . (int)$cat_id . "'");}
   
} but didnt work either...is that what you mean by updating the rest to 0?

Comment: The source page after the new checkbox is correct. But like you say it doesn't seem to set the rest to 0.